# How to use a time to refresh code

Tags: basic

I've never coded in my life and today is my first day I've got somewhere with it however I was wondering if someone could fill in the missing code so I can get my program to refresh ever 1 second. the point of the software is to show a a message to tell my when my SSD is low on space id like to to run in the background and refresh all the time the code looks like this:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Opacity = 0
    Me.Visible = False
    If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDriveInfo("C:\").TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) < 48 Then
        Form2.Show()
    End If
    'MsgBox(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDriveInfo("C:\").TotalFreeSpace)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
End Sub
End Class
```

if someone could help me id be ever so greateful bare in mind I literally know nothing about visual basic.

Comment: What version of BASIC is this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have declared the timer value, you must add the code to the timer function:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Rem put display code here..
End Sub
```